# Replacing Characters Within Parenthesis

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to come up with a regex that can space-separate all dashes that are within brackets. I have come up with the following:

```
regexprep(input, '(\w| +)-(\w+)(?=.*\))', '$1 - $2');
```

However, when running a string `(this-is-a-bigger-test)`, I obtain the result `(this - is-a - bigger-test)` instead of the expected `(this - is - a - bigger - test)`.

What am I missing in my grouping for this regex?

Comment: How do you know if its between parenthesis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
str_out = regexprep(str_in, '(?<=\(.*)-(?=.*\))', ' - ');
```

It replaces any `-` that is after a `(` and before a `)` by `-`.

As [noted by @stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865732/replacing-characters-within-parenthesis/28865891?noredirect=1#comment45996899_28865891), if a dash may already have one or more spaces on each side and you want each dash to have exactly one space on each side, use

```
str_out = regexprep(str_in, '(?<=\(.*)\s*-\s*(?=.*\))', ' - ');
```

Comment: In case of a "(this-is -a -bigger-test)", the regex needs updating: `(?<=\(.*)\s*-\s*(?=.*\))`.

Comment: @stribizhev Well thought! But for `'(this-is -a -  bigger-test)'` (double space before `bigger`) it would turn the double space into a single space. Not sure that's what the OP wants

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @stribzhev (and thanks to the OP for the original answer). This solves my problem.

Comment: Do you know what regex engine _matlab_ uses ?

Comment: @sln I don't know much about regular expressions, other than occasional use in Matlab. Maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/38277) helps